# security for android classes

Tags: android, security

before asking this question i searched hole internet about security of android and i know maybe proguard and obfuscation help me...
I have wrote a class that decrypt server response data and convert it to a map.
if anyone can decompile my java class or move my decryptor class to him app.he can cheat in my game and harmful financial damages.
if we cross "This is an stupid question!!!" then
is there any way to secure my code with 100% security?
what reference's you suggest me?

thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are multiple facets to this issue. Security is not just about android or java abstraction, you want your entire system to be strong enough. For starters I will suggest you can develop an apiKey system that will add another layer of security, the apikey is linked to the email id of the downloading user, so even if someone were to decompile your app they would need an api key to access your services. But api keys are for basic authorisation purposes.You could also opt for OAuth2.0 tokens which are time based and are much more robust.

These links can help:

https://hueniverse.com/introducing-oauth-2-0-b5681da60ce2
https://www.scribd.com/document/33655/How-to-Design-a-Good-API-and-Why-it-Matters